# Aligning center a tabel-cell div, and the correct hyper-link

Tags: html, css

I have the following simplified HTML code:

> ```
> <div>
>   <h2>XXX</h2>
>   <img XXX />
>   <a href="XXX"><div class="button" id="btback">back</div></a>
> </div>
> ```

And also the CSS code:

> .button {
>       text-align: center;
>       vertical-align: middle;
>       background-image: url(button.png);
>       width: 120px;
>       height: 60px;
>       display: table-cell;}
>
> #btback {
>       margin: 10px auto 10px auto;}

Basically, in a div, there is a headline and an image, below is a button. `button.png` is the button background image without any text. So I horizontally and vertically align the text above the button background.

The first problem is, the button cannot be horizontally aligned in center. If I don't use `display: table-cell`, it can aligned in center, but the text is not vertically aligned.

The second problem is, the entire horizontal area (margin area) of the button div can be clicked. But I want only the `120px` width area to be clickable.

An example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/cLSUT/

Comment: Make a jsfiddle with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove that inner div and just use the a tag as the button:

http://jsfiddle.net/cLSUT/2/

```
<div>
  <a class="button" id="btback" href="#">back</a>
</div>

.button { 
    text-align: center; 
    line-height:60px; 
    background-color: red; 
    width: 120px; 
    height: 60px; 
    display:block;
}

#btback { margin: 10px auto 10px auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

let me see if I understood.
try with this

```
div>a {
   text-align:center;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.button { 
  text-align: center; 
  background-image: url(button.png); 
  width: 120px; 
  height: 60px; 
  display: table-cell;
  line-height: 20px; /*(for example)*/
}
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: it doesn't work. 1) it is not an overflow problem; 2) I don't know why you replace vertical-align with line-height.